# Redirect to calling controller and action on HttpAntiForgeryException (ValidateAntiForgeryToken)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, stack-trace, antiforgerytoken

When a HttpAntiForgeryException is thrown, on the submission of any of my forms, I would like to redirect the user back to a clean version of the form (with new token) via the original Controller and Action that loaded the form view in the first place, and show an error message.

I believe this would make a good user experience, but I am not sure if it is possible or if there would be any security concerns.

At the moment I am looking at using `override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)` in my BaseController, but I cannot work out how to, or if I can, get the action and controller that tripped the exception. The action would be the httppost version, but would have the same name as the original action that loaded the form view.

Is there a way to get it from the stacktrace in filterContext.Exception?

Or is there a better way?

Or is this a silly idea?

Many thanks for your input :)

This is for an MVC 4 .Net 4.0 application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will take care of the exception in the manner you describe:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Exception is HttpAntiForgeryException)
    {
        this.RedirectToAction(
            filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), 
            filterContext.RouteData.Values);
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }

    base.OnException(filterContext);
}
```

The alternative is to use the HandleError attribute, but that only allows one to redirect to a given view (usually a custom error view). Finally, one could create a custom HandleError attribute by implementing the IExceptionFilter interface.

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to redirect me to the correct controller and action, but it just shows a blank page and does not hit the break point I have placed in the action it is redirecting to.